# Stuck with an ARRAY solution

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

since I am new on this platform I would like to ask something that could be pretty easy for all of you.

And I need to show a joining within the dates, so the dates do not repeat and if they have similars they join into one array.

```
$newarray = array();
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$fecha = $jsonOrdenado[0]['fecha_inicio']

foreach($jsonOrdenado as $a) {
    $newarray[$i]["fecha"] = $a['fecha_inicio'];
    $newarray[$j]["eventos"] = $a;

    if ($a['fecha_inicio'] == $a['fecha_inicio']) {
        $newarray[$i] = ($data[$i], $data[$a]);
        $i++;
    } else {
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The line $fecha = $jsonOrdenado[0]['fecha_inicio'] doesn't have a semicolon at the end. The variable $fecha is never used again. Also $a['fecha_inicio'] == $a['fecha_inicio'] will always be true.

Comment: Do we get any sample data to play with?  or an expected result given the to-be-provided sample input?

Comment: show the example of your input array and what you are excepting  as desire output, update your question

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array();

//this will combine the events by date
foreach($jsonOrdenado as $a) {
  $fecha = $a['fecha_inicio'];
  $newarray[$fecha]["eventos"] = $a;
}

//see what it looks like
print_r($newarray);
```

If there are duplicated events, use their names or whatever unique about them

```
foreach($jsonOrdenado as $a) {
  $fecha = $a['fecha_inicio'];
  //I don't know what your data looks like :)
  $eventname = $a['event_name_or_title_or_whatever']; 
  $newarray[$fecha]["eventos"][$eventname] = $a;
}

//see what it looks like
print_r($newarray);
```

If you want to simplify the format later...

```
foreach($newarray as $fecha => $whatever){ //only the key matters
    $newarray[$fecha]['eventos'] = array_values($newarray[$fecha]['eventos']);
}

//see what it looks like
print_r($newarray);
```